# Whitelisting IP Addresses

Tags: database, mongodb, security, networking, whitelist

I recently developed a web app and came across this concept of whitelisting. I just wanted to know on what basis does a developer whitelist IP addresses in MongoDB or any database ?

Do I have to whitelist if I am making a project just for a hackathon because the web-app is published on netlify and I am not able to find their IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Whitelist is the list of IP addresses that can access the relevant resource. It is a good practice to whitelist only your server to be able to access your database. Also, you can even whitelist IP addresses that can communicate to your server as well, and if your server got a request from somewhere that is not in whitelist, it will reject the request. Basically, whitelisting is a good security practice.